# Reference System.Windows.Forms

Tags: winforms, console

Inside a console application (.net 4.5 using vs 2013), it's just not possible for me to add a reference to this lib.(System.Windows.Forms). Have started the new console proj many times from scratch to no avail. Any clues? this seems like a very simple task... but well, it's anything but. (thanks)

[image]

Comment: The dialog does not look normal.  It is supposed to display the targeted .NET framework version above the list and show more info about the selected assembly (Created By and File Version).  You'll have to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... this was interesting. Started playing with the property settings and set the target framework to 4 client and was finally able to add the library. Tried to run and it didn't, then changed it back to .net 4.5 full and set the build platform target as x86 as someone suggested here on SO... and yes !! it worked. So, basically playing around with those settings got me running, but still think it might have been an environment issue and not the platform itself. ... thanks !

Answer (score 0):

NO there is no such issue with console application when we add reference with Windows.Forms library.

Close your visual studio and try again.

Comment: Thanks ... yeah, it's just so weird, I mean, I haven't had any issues with my VS, but this simple issue seems quite odd. (closing and opening did not work, btw).

Comment: Well, just realized, I cannot add any dll at all ! I'm using the right target framework (4.5), not client.